# How to initiate a UINavigationController push in response to a tap on a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using `UICollectionView`, but I am not able to navigate to another view when I tap a UICollectionViewCell.

Here is my code.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        AboutTheBook *alarmView1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AboutTheBook"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:alarmView1 animated:YES]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this method is being reached, i.e. you have set the delegate property of the UICollectionView?

Comment: this is not issue with delegate that is an issue User are not setting Navigation-controller so they can not push a view Controller from didSelect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

1. a navigation controller is embedded to the VC [or a VC in its flow above coming in the stack] that you are trying to push
2. `AboutTheBook` is the unique identifier of teh VC in storyboard
3. You are clicking at index 0 of the collection view

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
AboutTheBook *alarmView1=(AboutTheBook *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AboutTheBook"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:alarmView1 animated:YES];
```